# Recuperar dados Json com Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Estou recuperando um Json por Node/Axios e recebo a seguinte estrutura (A e B). Tenho 2 ocorrencias de
estabelecimentos.

### **resultado A**

```
{
  statuscod: 200,
  mensagem: null,
  dados: '{"estrutura":{"estabelecimentos":[{"idPropriedade":353359,"municipio"...
}
```

### **resultado B**

Resultado Json da variavel "dados"

```
    {
    "estrutura": {
        "estabelecimentos": [{
            "idPropriedade": 353359,
            "municipio": "Votuporanga",
            "uf": "SP",
        }, {
            "idPropriedade": 353366,
            "municipio": "Valentim Gentil",
            "uf": "SP",
        }],
        "qtde": 2
    }
}
```

No JS executando console.log(response.dados) ele mostra o **resultado B**, porém não consigo acessar os dados mais internos (uf do estabelecimentos, qtde por exemplo)
Já executei: 
 dados.GtaEstabelecimentosWSVO.estabelecimentos[0].uf
 dados.GtaEstabelecimentosWSVO.qtde
 mas sem sucesso. Poderia me ajudar dizendo o que está errado?
Acessando dados.statuscod retorna 200 (correto)

Comment: Aonde se lê GtaEstabelecimentosWSVO, leia-se estrutura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite ! Primeiramente gostaria de comentar que nas proximas vezes que fizer uma pergunta por aqui seria interressante mostrar o código que está sendo executado e os erros gerados durante a execução pois isso facilita a todos encontrar error e com certeza fará você obter uma resposta precisa muito mais rápido :) !

Mas de qualquer forma uma possibilidade é que `response.dados` apesar de ter a estrutura de um JSON é na verdade uma string. Logo `response.dados.qtde` não faz sentido pois uma string é basicamente uma lista de caracteres. Você pode testar essa hipotese fazendo `console.log(response.dados[0])` se isso imprimir na tela um caracter você tem certeza que essa variavel se trata de uma string.

Caso esse seja o caso tudo que precisa fazer é um parse da string para objeto JSON:

```
obj = JSON.parse(response.dados)
console.log(obj.qtde)
```

Você pode obter mais detalhes sobre [JSON.parse aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Lucas, agradeço a sua atenção e ajuda. Era exatamente isso o que você relatou. Problema resolvido. Abraços.

Comment: @Galvez lembra-te de marcar a resposta como aceite se ela resolveu e explicou o problema que tinhas.